# How can I choice different AppDelegate for the main entry?

Tags: ios, swift

I try to using [FolioReaderKit](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReaderKit) Epub reader, I am build the Example folder for examine, But there is many AppDelegate in separate folder within Example/ folder, Like following:

[image]

There are 3 examples, `Example/Example/`, `Example/Storyboard-Example/`, `Example/MultipleInstance-Example`, But the default is `Example/Example/` for build, How can I switch between the 3 examples when build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different targets. Choose from the scheme menu to select which one to build and run.

[image]

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Added a screen shot. :)